# Add quotes and brackets to every element of a list

Tags: python

I need to process a python list as below:

```
PGPrimary=['VDD', 'VSS', 'A', 'Y']
```

I need to change this list to below format:

```
//PG PRIMARY  ("VDD") ("VSS") ("A") ("Y")
```

I tried below code but  it doesn't work:

```
PGPrimary=['VDD', 'VSS', 'A', 'Y']
print("1:PGPrimary:",PGPrimary)

PGPrimary="//PG PRIMARY " + ' '.join(PGPrimary)
(','.join('("' + item + '")' for item in PGPrimary))


print("2:PGPrimary:",PGPrimary)
```

Here is the output:

```
('1:PGPrimary:', ['VDD', 'VSS', 'A', 'Y'])
('2:PGPrimary:', '//PG PRIMARY VDD VSS A Y')
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Can anyone point out why the code is not working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str.format` and `str.join`:

```
'//PG PRIMARY  {}'.format(' '.join('("{}")'.format(i) for i in PGPrimary))
```

- `'("{}")'.format(i) for i in PGPrimary)` iterates over the list elements and adds parentheses and quotes around each element
- `' '.join` joins the above resulting iterable

**Example:**

```
In [33]: PGPrimary=['VDD', 'VSS', 'A', 'Y']

In [34]: '//PG PRIMARY  {}'.format(' '.join('("{}")'.format(i) for i in PGPrimary))
Out[34]: '//PG PRIMARY  ("VDD") ("VSS") ("A") ("Y")'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PGPrimary=['VDD', 'VSS', 'A', 'Y']
print("1:PGPrimary:",PGPrimary)

PGPrimary="//PG PRIMARY " + ' '.join('("' + item + '")' for item in PGPrimary)
print("2:PGPrimary:",PGPrimary)
```